# python list comprehension with if condition looping

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Is it possible to use list comprehension for a dataframe if I want to change one column's value based on the condition of another column's value.

The code I'm hoping to make work would be something like this:

`return ['lower_level' for x in usage_time_df['anomaly'] if [y < lower_outlier for y in usage_time_df['device_years']]`

Thanks!

Comment: need more context, what is `lower_outlier` ?

Comment: lower_outlier was a predefined float for minimum "device_years" value, sorry for not explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want to do can be done in a list comprehension, and if it can, it will definitely not be efficient.

Assuming a dataframe `usage_time_df` with two columns, `anomaly` and `device_years`, if I understand correctly, you want to set the value in `anomaly` to `lower_level` when the value in `device_years` does not reach `lower_outlier` (which I guess is a float). The natural way to do that is:

```py
usage_time_df.loc[usage_time_df['device_years'] < lower_outlier, 'anomaly'] = 'lower_level'
```

Comment: Oh awesome, didn't know .loc. can be used with a condition mixed like that. Thanks so much!!